# Cargar un file desde una funcion de scope angular js

Tags: angularjs, mvc, fileupload

Tengo un boton type submit, el cual sube el file a su respectivo httppostfileBase, sin embargo quisiera cargarlo sin necesidad de que le den a ese boton submit si no en otro.

Comment: Eduardo, para que esta pregunta sirva a otros usuarios porque no agregas lo que describes en tu pregunta.Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible dar click a un botón sin importar en donde esté localizado y que este haga el submit, solamente debes vincular tu form a una funcion mediante el evento `ng-submit` y la misma función vincularla a un evento `ng-click`:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <form ng-submit="submit()" id="myForm">
            ...
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <button ng-click="submit()">Submit 2</button>
    </div>
 <button ng-click="submit()">Submit 3</button>
</div>
```

Pero a partir de ahí dejas de usar Angular y dentro del controller de Angular usas vanilla Javascript como lo siguiente:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
```

La otra opción para seguir usando Angular es mandar el fichero mediante AJAX.